# Mongoose returns empty array when selecting property whose type is NumberLong?

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

So, I'm using mongoose-long.

This is my query code in mongoose where I have hardcoded valid string.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);

var Long = mongoose.Types.Long;
let makertags = await Markertag.find({ 'photoId': Long.fromString('5853748089061376') });
```

Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);
const SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

let schema = mongoose.Schema({
    photoId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Long },
    eventId: { type: String }  
 });
```

This is the mongoose query debug

```
markertags.find({ photoId: Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: -277610496, high_: 1362931 } }, { fields: {} });


{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5caf6e18241cb90c791157a5"), 
"id" : "ahFzfnBpYzJnby1wcm9kLWhyZHIWCxIJTWFya2VyVGFnGICA0OvHkYYJDA", 
"photoId" : NumberLong(4503749505843200), 
"markerNum" : NumberInt(531)
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5caf6e18241cb90c791157a6"), 
    "id" : "ahFzfnBpYzJnby1wcm9kLWhyZHIWCxIJTWFya2VyVGFnGICA0LurouQIDA", 
    "photoId" : NumberLong(4503851813306368), 
    "markerNum" : NumberInt(405)
}
```

I'm not sure how can I make this right cause I keep getting empty array.

Comment: Can you update your question to show your schema and the document you're expecting to find?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I updated the question with schems

Comment: thanks...and the document you're expecting to find?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I want to find the Markertag where  { photoId :'213123213' }
const Markertag = mongoose.model('Markertag', schema);

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but to figure this out it's vital that you provide an example document that your query should be returning, but isn't. That way we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I have updated

Comment: Neither of those docs match your query, but if I query for `{photoId: Long.fromString('4503749505843200')}` it returns that doc as expected.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes, thats the exact problem, the above query works but doing the same query using mongoose and mongoose-long doesnt return data

Comment: I was using mongoose and mongoose-long to do that query with your schema and document.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I ended using, just use the raw query :D

const collection = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('markertags');
const makertags = await collection.find({'photoId': Long.fromString(search.searchText)}).toArray();

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that though, and the mongoose query worked fine for me.